# Could not process the request "cURL"

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

i created a function to send xml data using curl, when i hit the function then got a message on my browser "Could not process the request", not understand whats wrong with code, below is my function:

```
    function otp_data_send($xmlblock='',$url='' ){
   $otp_xml_data = htmlentities($xmlblock);
   $headers = array(
   "Content-type: text/xml",
   "Content-length: " . strlen($otp_xml_data),
   "Connection: close",
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $otp_xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $data = var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
    // print_r($data);exit;
    echo $data;
    if(curl_errno($ch))
       print curl_error($ch);
    else
       curl_close($ch);

 }
```

and call this function inside another function. Please help

Comment: The error is showing on any particular website or on other ones also!!

Comment: Why echoing in a function? o.O

Comment: when i hit google.co.in url then google page is display, but when i tried above code got could not process the request

Comment: With `curl_errno()` you must return numbers, so I think that the error that you see come from the website.

Comment: @Maverick No when i debug the code and echo $data and exit(); The error was same, when i hit same url using postman it works

Comment: @codex run the code in my answer and paste the error that you get

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get a more detailed error

```
function otp_data_send($xmlblock='',$url='' ){
   $otp_xml_data = htmlentities($xmlblock);
   $headers = array(
   "Content-type: text/xml",
   "Content-length: " . strlen($otp_xml_data),
   "Connection: close",
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $otp_xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        return 'Curl error: [' . curl_errno($ch) . '] ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        return 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }
}

echo otp_data_send(...);
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
function otp_data_send($xmlblock='',$url='' ){
   $otp_xml_data = htmlentities($xmlblock);
   $headers = array(
   "Content-type: text/xml",
   "Content-length: " . strlen($otp_xml_data),
   "Connection: close",
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $otp_xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return '[' . $info . ']' . $output;
}

echo otp_data_send(...);
```

Comment: It successfully completed but why i dont get any response? It returns "Operation completed without any errors"
The url give me xml response

Comment: So, as I said, the problem come from the website

Comment: @codex Try the code below the "UPDATE 1" and post the response

Comment: when i hit url using postman , below is the response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OtpRes txn="" err="530" code="e794efd7fd91482c8ada9e0607764910" ts="2015-08-31T16:52:26.141+05:30" ret="n"/>

Comment: You returned a 530 error that means "Failed authentication" or "Login incorrect"

Comment: Hi @Maverick this error 530 is the api error meaning of this 530 error is something else. when i tried ur code i got 500 error.Thanks for ur precious help :-)